# Getting full word with Matchers / Patterns

Tags: java, regex

In my Bukkit plugin I'm making an advertisement blocker, and am getting the words through a pattern and matcher. Although, I am going more in depth with it and not just looking for the numbers . numbers etc, I'm looking if there are a specific amount of .'s in the statement, and if it is 4, block the message. But, when I get the String with matcher.group() it only gives me the blocked part, not the full word with the rest of chars.

Is there a way to find get the whole word / char sequence instead of part of it from the pattern?

Editerino because I'm bad at explaining things:
I am trying to get the full word of the string which is found by the pattern and matcher, hope this isn't as confusing ;-;

Comment: Please try to make it easier to understand what you're trying to do. Some examples of good and bad input could help, also if you could share some patterns you've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure this is what you're asking, but `group(0)` will return the entire match.

For example:

```
String str = "asdf asdf asdf asdf";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("SOME_REGEX_HERE");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
if (m.find()) {
  System.out.println(m.group(0));
}
```

Comment: I already have this. What I'm trying to do is get there rest of the word that contains 1-4 .'s, but right now if I typed 10.0.0.199.9.10 and got it to print out m.group(), only 10.0.0.199 would come out. I am trying to get the rest of the word so I can do further actions.

Comment: what is the regex you are using? is 10.0.0.199.9.10 something you want to match? it has more than 4 dots...

Comment: The regex I am using is:
([0-9]{1,3}\\.){3}[0-9]{1,3})(\\:[0-9]{2,5}) for getting the numbers.

Comment: Figured it out, instead of using if (m.find()), I was using while (m.find()).
This fixed it for me, thanks.